# Laravel 4.2 ODBC authentication error

Tags: laravel, odbc

Is there any solution for the following error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] SQLDriverConnect: 18452 [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. The
>   user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

The username and password looks to be correct in the app/config files but still no luck

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem in your SQL Server. [Searching](https://www.google.com/#q=SQLSTATE%5B28000%5D+SQLDriverConnect%3A+18452+%5BunixODBC%5D%5BMicrosoft%5D%5BODBC+Driver+11+for+SQL+Server%5D%5BSQL+Server%5DLogin+failed+for+user+%27%27.+The+user+is+not+associated+with+a+trusted+SQL+Server+connection.) in Google I have find some help:

- https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/2121736
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555332

Comment: By the looks of the error it seems like i'm not passing a user? But I am